# array radio button for quiz

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

i have created a quiz format like QCM examen
first i used radio button only
and the problem of this radio button must have a name with the id of the question
and the value must be the id of the answer
example :
the php code (using while)

```
<input type="radio" name="question_['.$question_id.']" value="'.$ans_id.'">
```

output

```
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="5">
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="6">
<input type="radio" name="question_2" value="10">
<input type="radio" name="question_2" value="11">
```

so what i want is posting this form i already used the `var_dump` for this but i've get an array format so i don't how to `foreach` it
so please can someone help me ?

Comment: could you provide your var_dump and give us an example of what you want? I'm just slightly confused.

Comment: thank you guys it's done scrowler get it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should generate an array in your `$_POST` or `$_GET` superglobal just like any other PHP array, you can iterate over it like this:

```
foreach($_POST['question_'] as $question_id => $answer) {
    echo 'Answer for Question #' . $question_id . ' is: ' . $answer . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Edit**: This example is following your first line of code - the second block of code is different and would not be produced by looping the first. You should definitely use the first style not the second, as arrays are much easier to loop over in this scenario than an arbitrary number of elements named like `question_1`, `question_2` etc.

Comment: thank you very much :) just a litle question what you mean with PHP_EOL ?

Comment: It's just a line break, like `\n`

Comment: Specifically, "EOL" means "End-Of-Line".